# Recursive Level-Order Traversal Switching Values

Tags: java, tree, traversal

When some data sets are inserted into the tree, values in the level order traversal are swapped incorrectly. I know I have made some logic mistake somewhere but I've not been able to figure out where the problem is.

I've tried reversing the traversal left/right right/left as well as modifying the logical operators to attempt to figure out why the problem is occuring. Debugger was not much help either.

```
    public void levelOrder() {
        int h = getHeightHelper(root);
        int i; 
    for (i = 1; i <= h; i++)
        printLevelHelper(root, i);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private int getHeightHelper(BinaryNode<?> root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0; 
    else { 
        int leftHeight = getHeightHelper(root.left); 
        int rightHeight = getHeightHelper(root.right);

            if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
                return(leftHeight + 1); 
            else
            return (rightHeight + 1); 
    }
    }

    private void printLevelHelper(BinaryNode<?> root, int level) {
        if (root == null)
            return; 
        if (level == 1)
            System.out.print(root.element + " ");
        else if (level > 1) {
             printLevelHelper(root.left, level - 1);
             printLevelHelper(root.right, level - 1);
        }
    }
    private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t ) {
        if( t == null )
            return new BinaryNode<>( x, null, null ); 

        int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element ); 

        if( compareResult < 0 )
            t.left = insert( x, t.left ); 
        else if( compareResult > 0 )
            t.right = insert( x, t.right );
        else
            ; // Duplicate, do nothing. 
        return t; 
    }
```

When 8, 2, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13 is entered: 
The expected level-order is 
8, 2, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13
However the following is the result. The 1 and 6 are reversed. 
8, 2, 10, 6, 1, 14, 4, 7, 13

Comment: how are you adding elements into your tree? perhaps the problem lies there

Comment: Above implementation seems fine. Please add code for adding element into your tree.

Comment: @ChrisGong - I added that insertion code. Thank you for taking the time to look over this. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Roy there doesn't seem to be an issue from what I see. What does your BinaryNode constructor look like?